Does the ice on top of a frozen lake act as an adiabatic wall?
Since the water under the ice on lake does not come in contact with outside and no heat comes in or goes out then can we say that the ice formed on top of the lake is an adiabatic wall?

It is not that “no” heat is transferred, only that the water under the ice is cooled significantly less than would otherwise be expected.

The ice top is not adiabatic.  Heat is conducted from the fluid below to the air above.

If you’re asking whether or not the “wall of ice” would meet the definition of an adiabatic boundary in thermodynamics, then the answer would be no. That’s because, by definition, an adiabatic boundary prevents energy transfer in the form of heat to or from the system enclosed by that boundary. It (the boundary) theoretically doesn’t absorb or supply heat.
Considering the liquid water underneath the ice as the “system”, if its temperature is greater than the ice there would be energy transfer from the system to the ice in the form of heat. Thus the ice wouldn’t constitute an adiabatic boundary. In effect, the ice would constitute the surroundings, with the boundary being the surface between the water and the ice.
Hope this helps.
